# ASP.Net - how to have multiple submit buttons and also submit the form via javascript?

Tags: asp.net, controller, submit, viewmodel, form-submit

I'm new to ASP.Net and am trying to make a web application using MVC2.

On one particular page I need to have multiple submit buttons - after reading up from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) I found [this method](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx) which worked well in my project.

So I have a few submit buttons handled in my controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(Key = "action", Value = "Button1")]
        public ActionResult Action1(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{ //do stuff
return View(newViewModel)
}

[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(Key = "action", Value = "Button2")]
     public ActionResult Action2(MyViewModel myViewModel)
```

My problem is that now I want to also postback my form on various client events. I tried to do this in the view by using javascript in there somewhere.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController")){ %> 
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

With a 'normal' action on the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
    }
```

But when I add this, now the multiple submit buttons do not work properly due to an ambiguous match exception between Action1 and Index. I realise that they have the same signature but as a beginner, I'm a bit stuck at this point!

What can I do to get all the different submit options working together? Please advise and/or point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you (instead) raise the click event on the appropriate button via Javascript - e.g. (jquery) `$("#<%=the_right_asp_button.ClientID %>").click();`

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I did not think of doing it this way as I just wanted the form to postback on a certain client event, and didn't have a button for it. I did not want to have an extra 'submit' button on the page, so in the end I just made the new button hidden with `style="display: none"` and then called the click from javascript. By the way, I couldn't get your code to work so instead did something like `document.getElementById("HiddenSubmit").click();` - anyway thanks for the help! If you put this as an answer will be happy to accept.